# How do I read in this csv-file in python? (3 commas (,,,) in each row)

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I tried

```
measurements = np.loadtxt(fname = 'TEK0001.CSV', delimiter = ',')
```

which gives back an error message: "could not convert string to float".

The data is obtained from an oszilloscope. I want to read in the csv file as a two dimensional array which I then can plot.

Csv-file: TEK0001.CSV

```
,,,00.000000055000,  -0.18400,
,,,00.000000056000,  -0.18400,
,,,00.000000057000,  -0.18400,
,,,00.000000058000,  -0.20000,
,,,00.000000059000,  -0.20800,
,,,00.000000060000,  -0.21600,
,,,00.000000061000,  -0.22400,
,,,00.000000062000,  -0.22400,
,,,00.000000063000,  -0.24000,
,,,00.000000064000,  -0.23200,
,,,00.000000065000,  -0.23200,
,,,00.000000066000,  -0.21600,
,,,00.000000067000,  -0.20000,
,,,00.000000068000,  -0.19200,
,,,00.000000069000,  -0.17600,
,,,00.000000070000,  -0.16000,
,,,00.000000071000,  -0.15200,
,,,00.000000072000,  -0.13600,
,,,00.000000073000,  -0.14400,
,,,00.000000074000,  -0.12800,
,,,00.000000075000,  -0.12800,
,,,00.000000076000,  -0.12800,
,,,00.000000077000,  -0.12800,
,,,00.000000078000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000079000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000080000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000081000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000082000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000083000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000084000,  -0.11200,
,,,00.000000085000,  -0.11200,
,,,00.000000086000,  -0.12000,
,,,00.000000087000,  -0.12800,
,,,00.000000088000,  -0.12800,
,,,00.000000089000,  -0.13600,
,,,00.000000090000,  -0.13600,
,,,00.000000091000,  -0.14400,
,,,00.000000092000,  -0.14400,
,,,00.000000093000,  -0.14400,
,,,00.000000094000,  -0.15200,
,,,00.000000095000,  -0.13600,
,,,00.000000096000,  -0.14400,
,,,00.000000097000,  -0.15200,
,,,00.000000098000,  -0.15200,
,,,00.000000099000,  -0.16000,
,,,00.000000100000,  -0.16800,
,,,00.000000101000,  -0.16800,
,,,00.000000102000,  -0.17600,
,,,00.000000103000,  -0.19200,
,,,00.000000104000,  -0.19200,
,,,00.000000105000,  -0.20800,
,,,00.000000106000,  -0.20000,
,,,00.000000107000,  -0.21600,
```

Comment: `np.genfromtxt` handles missing values better than `loadtxt`.  But if the `usecols` solution works, use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas mean that cells are empty, also an extra comma at the end of each line must be stripped. A workaround is to explicitly specify which columns to parse. For that you can use `usecols` argument which in your case has value `[3,4]`

```py
np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=[3,4])
```